# Conflicting declaration of character

Tags: c++, arduino, iot, esp32

I am currently working on an Arduino project where I need both the WiFi.h and MySQL_Connection.h libraries.

The variable "password" is used in both of these libraries and therefore causes a conflict.

How can I fix this problem? I am still quite new to the platform, and any possible solutions must therefore be easy to understand. Thanks in advance.

Error message provided by Arduino:  "exit status 1 conflicting declaration 'char password []'"

```
include <Ethernet.h>
#include "WiFi.h";
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

//Wifi

//Wifi connection, this call is to the Wifi.h library
const char* ssid = "pp******";
const char* password = "*******";

//This call is to the <MySQL_Connection.h> library

IPAddress server_addr(10,0,1,35);  // IP of the MySQL *server* here
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "secret";        // MySQL user login password
```

Comment: This `password` variable comes form external libraries or is it defined by you?

Comment: Wow, that sounds really bad. But what you should do is cut and paste the error message you are getting into the question. Also the error message will refer to some code somewhere, you should also cut and paste that code into the question. Without this kind of context it hard to know what suggestions to make.

Comment: I'm a little bit familar with MySQL and I find it hard to believe that what you describe is really true of that library. So it's possible you are mistaken about the cause of the error you are seeing. Which is all the more reason that you need to provide more information.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply. The password variable is defined from an external library (Wifi.h and MySQL_Connection.h) . The error message is "exit status 1 conflicting declartion 'char password []'

Comment: Why can't you just change the name password to something else in one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd pick the header which provides fewer things to your code, and put it in a namespace:

```
#include "WiFi.h"

namespace mySQL
{
#include "MySQL_Connection.h"
}

using mySQL::something;
using mySQL::something_else;

...

foo(password);
bar(mySQL::password);
```

**EDIT:** It's not clear to me how the code you've posted works, but try this:

```
include <Ethernet.h>

namespace Wifi
{
#include "WiFi.h";
const char* password = "*******";
}
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

const char* ssid = "pp******";

IPAddress server_addr(10,0,1,35);  // IP of the MySQL *server* here
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "secret";        // MySQL user login password
```

If this doesn't work, tell me the result in a comment and we'll tinker some more. If it works, be advised that you still have to put in the effort to learn about namespaces.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the function namespace and I am not quite sure if I understand how this could solve the problem.

Comment: @Kevin: Name collision is the problem that namespaces exist to solve. You will find tutorials all over the web, but basically they divide the global space into named domains, so that two things with the same name don't come into conflict. After I posted this answer you edited your question to add code; if you [remove the unneeded parts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code example, and indicate which call is to which library, I can show you how to use `namespace` to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. - Then I will watch a few tutorials:). I just removed the unneeded parts and specified which variables who call to the different libraries.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will definitely put in the effort to learn namespaces.